# I'm trying to do something about firebase realtime database but I get an exports error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I'm trying to do something about firebase realtime database, but I'm getting such an error can you help?

```
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in C:\Users\efeba\Desktop\test2\node_modules\firebase\package.json
    at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:299:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:522:3)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:449:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:489:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\efeba\Desktop\test2\app.js:1:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase js sdk is for client-side use only. In order to interact with Firebase from your backend environment (ie cloud functions, node backend, etc), you must use the admin-sdk.

Keep in mind that since the admin-sdk runs in a secure, trusted environment, it has elevated privileges and will bypass security rules, so make sure you're validating your data in your functions.

You can view the full documentation for the admin-sdk here: ([Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin))

Comment: *firebaser here* While the Admin SDK is a valid option to access Firebase from a trusted environment, the regular Firebase SDK can also be used in Node.js in case of a non-trusted environment (most common IoT). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node

Comment: Thank you... didn't know about that.
Thank you for letting me know.